# Why is the int in try compiled into byte

Tags: java, int, try-catch, byte

I find a phenomenon:

```
public class TryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test1());
    }

    public static int test1() {
        try {
            int a = 127;
            return a;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }finally {
            System.out.println("I am finally");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

compiled to .class:

```
public class TryTest {
    public TryTest() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test1());
    }

    public static int test1() {
        try {
            int a = 127;
            byte var1 = a;
            return var1;
        } catch (Exception var5) {
        } finally {
            System.out.println("I am finally");
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

why "int a" convert to "byte var1"?
Is the purpose to save memory?
Isn't this unnecessary?
I want to know how the compiler handles this.

but I find if code like this:

```
    public static int test3() {
        int a = 1;
        return a;
    }
```

compiled to .class:

```
    public static int test3() {
        int a = 1;
        return a;
    }
```

If there is no "try", it will not be compiled into "byte"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to look at what something is compiled into in Java, you shouldn't look at the decompiled code. Converting a `.class` file back into a `.java` file involves a lot of interpretation (one could even say guessing) and should not be taken as an indication what the actual compilation looks like. Look at the `javap -v` output instead, that will show you the actual bytecode. The bytecode of your method looks like this (I removed some unnecessary detail, run it yourself to check it all):

```
  public static int test1();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=0
         0: bipush        127
         2: istore_0
         3: iload_0
         4: istore_1
         5: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         8: ldc           #5                  // String I am finally
        10: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        13: iload_1
        14: ireturn
        15: astore_0
        16: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        19: ldc           #5                  // String I am finally
        21: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        24: goto          38
        27: astore_2
        28: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        31: ldc           #5                  // String I am finally
        33: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        36: aload_2
        37: athrow
        38: iconst_0
        39: ireturn
      Exception table:
         from    to  target type
             0     5    15   Class java/lang/Exception
             0     5    27   any
```

Nothing in there indicates that anything is stored in a `byte` (`iload_*` and `istore_*` load and store integer values).

The only byte-specific instruction is `bipush` which pushes a *byte value*, but it will be extended to an `int` value on the stack. This simply saves a couple of bytes over `sipush` (push a `short` constant) or `ldc` (which would require the value to be stored in the constant pool).

The `istore_1` is used to remember the value to be returned while the finally block is executed (8-10). Then we use `iload_1` to load it back out and return it.

The decompiler probably thinks that this is an actual variable, when it's just a synthetic constructed caused by the try-catch-finally construct.

Also, you might notice that the bytecode looks horribly inefficient, but that' simply because the `javac` compiler does a very straight-forward translation into bytecode and really doesn't do any optimizations. Any actual optimizations (such as never actually storing *any* values in *any* variables but simply returning the constant value `127`) will be done by the JVM at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Java decompilers are notorious for producing odd looking, incorrect and even non-compilable Java code from bytecodes.  You cannot infer that the Java compiler has compiled a Java source file in a particular way by looking at the decompiled code.

But you don't need to.  Just use `java -p` to convert the bytecodes into a readable form, and then lookup what the bytecode instructions mean in the JVM specification.

If you do it in this case (as @Joachim has done), you will see that there is no actually conversion to a `byte` in the bytecodes.  The decompiler has got it wrong ... but that should not be a big surprise.

My understanding of the logic of this sequence

```
 0: bipush        127
 2: istore_0
 3: iload_0
 4: istore_1
 5: getstatic     #2  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
 8: ldc           #5  // String I am finally
10: invokevirtual #6  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
13: iload_1
14: ireturn
```

is that the compiler has emitted the instruction at 4: to save the return expression in a temporary variable so that it can "inline" the code in the `finally` block.  At 13: it reloads the value and returns it.

But the `istore_1` and `iload_1` instructions are restoring and then loading an `int` value.  The decompiler is just confused.

Answer (score -7):

The value of 127 can be stored inside a byte, so it's trying to save on memory.

Comment: but If there is no "try", it will not be compiled into "byte"

Comment: Really? That's interesting. From my understanding it should be compiled into `byte` in both cases...

Comment: There is no "trying" to save on memory. The bytecode sequence is unambiguous in what it does, but is ambiguous in how it can be decompiled. The particular decompiler used here happens to yield this interpretation when try/catch related structures are present in the bytecode.